# showing error while i install seven-square in my ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt

Showing error when i install seven-square in my ubuntu 18.04.
When i type "cp -vf build/seven-square /usr/bin/".
What should i do.[this error show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfY8p.png)

Comment: Please, @UbaidAwan, structure your question and try to explain the problem you're facing in steps that are clear and can be understood easily.

Comment: To start, your shell prompt shows you are already in the `build` subdirectory - so unless you have a `build/build/` directory tree, you will need to go up one level (or remove the leading `build/`). Also don't forget you will need root privileges to copy files to `/usr/bin` (FWIW I'd put 3rd party executables in `/usr/local/bin` anyhow).

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot shows that You first enter `build` directory and then try to copy `seven-square` **from** `build` directory You're **already in**. That's why the "No such file or directory" error appears.

The solution is to simply not call `cd build` in all this process.

```
cd seven-square-master
cp -vf build/seven-square /usr/bin/
```

Also, as [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) mentioned in the comment, You may need root privilages to change `/usr/bin` content, so You may have to use `sudo cp -vf build/seven-square /usr/bin/`.

By the way - I personally would not call coping the file or folder to `/usr/bin` installing. If I were to do that though I'd use `-s` parameter, which makes a symbolic link instead of coping the file or folder, or - eventually - `-l` which makes a hard link.